# Convert `ref SomeStruct` to IntPtr

Tags: c#, interop

I have the following overload

```
public void SendMessage(IntPtr wParam)
{
   // ...
}
```

I have a struct, e.g.

```
public struct BlittableStruct
{
    public int x;
}
```

I want to define an overload to `SendMessage` that calls the IntPtr overload.

```
public void SendMessage(ref BlittableStruct bs)
{
    SendMessafe(???);
}
```

So: how can I convert this ref to a blittable struct to an IntPtr in c#

Performance is important, so the highest perf option is ideal. I also need to keep reference semantics so `Marshal.StructureToPtr` is not an option.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that would be possible get an `IntPtr` referencing an `Blittable` struct. 1st - `structs` uses heap memory spaces and objects uses stack. 2nd there's no covariance between `Blittable` and `IntPtr`

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple. You need to use fixed statement and then convert it's pointer into `IntPtr`. Do not forget to enable unsafe code!

The code:

```cs
public void SendMessage(IntPtr wParam)
{
   // ...
}

public unsafe void SendMessage(ref BlittableStruct bs)
{
    fixed (BlittableStruct* pBlittableStruct = &bs)
    {
        SendMessage((IntPtr)pBlittableStruct);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the BlittableStruct from managed memory to unmanaged memory. 
 Try following :

```
        public void SendMessage(BlittableStruct bs)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(bs));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(bs, ptr, true);
            SendMessage(ptr);
        }
```

Comment: My intention is to modify the original struct being passed in, so ref semantics are quite important ! What do you think about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.aspointer?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_Unsafe_AsPointer__1___0__

Comment: You are defeating the purpose of managed code.  Microsoft developed the managed code to minimize the number of Blue Screen Exception which killed the PC.  Using Unsafe increases the probability of Blue Screen.  If you want to use unsafe code then program in c++.